# Jquery for each image

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var klient = 'accesstokencode';
    var firstlink = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,posts&access_token='+klient;
    $.getJSON(firstlink, function(dayta){

        var haitchteaemel = "";
        var el = $('#facebookapi'); 
            $.each(dayta.posts.data, function(key, val){

                function runner(){
                    if (val.message){
                        return val.message;
                    }
                    else if (!val.message){
                        return val.story;
                    }
                }

        var secondlink = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/'+val.id+'?fields=attachments&access_token='+klient;                      
            $.getJSON(secondlink, function(beyta){
                    var target = beyta.attachments.data[0].media.image.src;
                    console.log(target);
                    $('.imageplace').attr("src", target);
            });

                    haitchface += `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <p>`+runner()+`</p>
                    <img class="imageplace"/>
                    </div>`;
            });
        el.html(haitchteamel);
    });
});
```

I am trying to use the Facebook API to get both posts and any accompanying images those posts may have. However, this question is not specific to the Facebook api, and is more of a logic issue on my end.

To give you all some context, the Facebook Graph API as is does not show each post from your images in one call. You can get your posts, but not the accompanying images. As is, you have to make a separate API call using the post ID to get it.

The present issue in my code is that while I am console logging each photo of each post correctly, my `.imageplace` div only shows one image across all of my `.imageplace` divs.

How might I modify my code with the appropriate for loop to display each `imageplace` class with the appropriate post image?

Comment: `$('.imageplace')` <-- this selects all your divs. Therefore you set the source image for *all* of them. You need to build a more specific selector, like using IDs or something like `$('.imageplace').eq(index)` where index will change from one image to the next.

Comment: I added a `for (i = 0; i < $('.imageplace').length; i++){$('.imageplace').eq(i).attr("src", target);}` which still does not work.

Comment: I am on mobile so I cannot check but you seem to be creating the `.imageplace` elements *after* the jQuery call. This won't work. You need to make this DOM available before fiddling with it. Anyway, your best bet is to create these elements already populated with data. Like this for example: Initialize an `images` array at the top and then for each AJAX call do `images.push($('<img/>', {class: 'imageplace', src: target}))`. Then at the end you can render the array somewhere using jQuery's `append` method like `$(somewhere).append(images)`. Just an idea. I'll see tomorrow on the PC.

Comment: _“You can get your posts, but not the accompanying images. As is, you have to make a separate API call using the post ID to get it.”_ – no, you don’t. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion

Comment: Looked over it again and I don't actually find the command for getting the post image command. When getting the post, your data looks like `posts: {data: [{"message": "wutevs", "created_time": "wutevs", "id": "wutevs"}]}`. I can't find the link to the image, nor the command that will let me get it. If however I use the POST ID `GET->/v.28/POSTIDHERE?fields=attachments` then I get `{attachments:{data:[{description: "etc", media: {image:{src: thelinktotheimage}}}]}}` hopefully I missed something here and I am completely wrong about this as it would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: To add to what I was saying, the request for finding your posts is done via `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,posts&access_token=thetokenhere` I was not able to find a command therein that let me find the image accompanying each post.

Comment: `?fields=posts{attachments,other-fields-you-might-need}`

Comment: Thanks! This solves it.